# Docusign: Sandbox works 100%, fails in production when adding a FORMULATAB

Tags: php, docusignapi

We have successfully implemented and tested the Docusign API service for a client. I've added a formula tab, which calculates the the value of 3 different fields. It works great and it works with the sandbox. But It doesnt work in production. Since its working in the sandbox and not in production, I dont know where to try to look or dump to trace the issue.

```
$dev_formula_tabs = [
    new FormulaTab([
        "tab_label" => "hasOneCheckedCheckbox",
        "formula"   => $formula_calculation_string,
        "required"  => "true",
        "locked"    => "false",
        "anchor_string" => "string_to_look_for_on_the_pdf",
        "anchor_x_offset"              => "-20",
        "anchor_y_offset"              => "0",
        "anchor_ignore_if_not_present" => "true",
        "anchor_units"                 => 'pixels',
        "round_decimal_places"         => "0",
        "validation_pattern"           => "^[1-9]*$",
        "validation_message"           => "own valiation message",
        "font_color"                   => "white",
    ]),
];
```

I'm getting a 400 error back

Comment: Response: `{"bad_request":true,"message":"[400] Error connecting to the API (https://au.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/*****/envelopes)"}`

Comment: API request logging is documented here: https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging
Can you post the DocuSign error message that's returned, if not a full API log of your envelope creation attempt?

Comment: ```
  "errorCode": "ACCOUNT_LACKS_PERMISSIONS",
  "message": "This Account lacks sufficient permissions. This envelope has calculated fields.  This account is not setup to use calculated fields."
```

Answer (score 1):

the error `"ACCOUNT_LACKS_PERMISSIONS": "This Account lacks sufficient permissions. This envelope has calculated fields. This account is not setup to use calculated fields."` means that formula fields are not enabled on your account. I'd recommend reaching out to either your Account Manager or the Sales team to see what would need to be done to enable that.